SPI goes low too fast; Raspberry Pi Pico PIO and ADS7042
I am trying to use an ADS7042 (12-bit ADC) with my Raspberry Pi Pico with the Pico's PIO, but the signal goes low too fast and it seems to have problems going high sometimes, do I need to add some pull resistors or something else to make it work?

Blue = clock from Pico,
Red = data from ADC
the clock is running at around 6MHz
The first couple of bits seem fine, but then on bits 5 and 6 it looks like it is trying to go high but fails, and at bit 8 it goes low on the clock's rising edge but I would expect it to continue to begin high until the falling edge.
This is the circuit I am using:

Edit: I forgot to put a ground on Ainm but Ainm is connected directly to ground

It is sampled on rising edge, but the bit 5 and 6 looks like whey should be high but not getting op where

You ask us to comment on a timing issue, but don't provide any timing information. I suggest you start by reading the datasheet, and comparing what you're doing with that. For example, the maximum SPI clock is specified as 16 MHz, how does your clock speed compare? There are also constraints on the CS-to-clock timing you need to check; if you keep to the timing specified in the datasheet, everything should be fine, no need for any extra resistors.

sorry I forgot, it is running at around 6 MHz i have updated the post

Data sheet link where I took this image: -

And, here's where you have an error: -

All bets are off with this significant circuit error.

it is a mistake I made in the Circuit diagram, my setup has Ainm grounded, I will update the main post

Then I think you need to show an image of just what your set up is because clearly you haven't used the schematic to make a PCB else it would be wrong on the PCB too.

it is not a pcb it is on a soldier less prototype bord

I just made a schematic of it is easier to see

Breadboard is your likely problem. You should look at the clock signal on the adc

Should a breadboard not be fine for spi?

the probes was next to the adc then testing

All sorts of problems happen with breadboard because you get inductance loops with the wires and, without a ground-plane any attachments to what you think is ground can prove to be several volts different on fast signals.

the problem seems to disappear then remove the oscilloscope from the clock pin, so I have the feeling the oscilloscope was disturbing the signal.
i am using a picoscope 2204a oscilloscope.

The problem is breadboard causing the symptom of scope probing appearing to be the problem.

this might be a dumb question but if I soldier it together it should be fine?

Is it x1 probe or x10 probe? x1 probe has high capacitance so it will wreck your clock. Also 6MHz clock on solderless breadboard is going to be ... troublesome.

Not necessarily. You might get lucky if the wire loops are not too bad but, without a ground plane, you are asking for trouble.

it is a TA3775 probe from picoscope, witch has both 1x and 10x but was set to 1x
